# I have a problem with Maven 3.8.4 that not allowed to authorize our private repo on Apache Archiva

Tags: maven, authentication, archiva

I have installed Maven 3.8.4 with homebrew on Macbook M1 CPU recently and I have ~/.m2/settings.xml properly containing the Apache Archiva user name and password.

when I executed  `mvn help:effective-settings -DshowPasswords=true` command I can see the correct xml content. But when I run  `mvn clean package` I get something like that

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for company.webshop:webshop-common:jar:21.11.12:
 Could not transfer artifact company.webshop:webshop-common:pom:21.11.12 
from/to company (https://repo.company.com/repository/internal/): 
authorization failed for https://repo.company.com/repository/internal/company/webshop/webshop-
common/21.11.12/webshop-common-21.11.12.pom,
 status: 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
```

when I try to access https://repo.company.com/repository/internal/ address from my browser I can login and see the artifacts properly as well. More than that other team members don't live any problem.

I also removed maven and reinstalled but nothing changed.

any idea?

Comment: I also tried Robert A. Decker 's approach in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228083/maven-2-works-but-maven-3-gives-authentication-error-with-same-settings-and-serv

and didn't work out.

Comment: Please show your setting in your settings.xml...

Comment: ```<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

   <localRepository/>
   <interactiveMode/>
   <usePluginRegistry/>
   <offline/>
   <pluginGroups/>
   <mirrors/>
   <proxies/>
   <profiles/>
   <activeProfiles/>

   <servers>
     <server>
       <id>company</id>
       <username>user</username>
       <password>Password1234</password>
     </server>
   </servers>
 </settings>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that after removing the folders (under the .m2 folder) related to our private repo, and re-run the maven after a fresh instalment it's working properly.

Maven was not downloading the  artifacts I guess, since there is a folder of that version number and only showing the content of old files which says something like "not authorized to the repo." and was miss leading